# HTML table borders not showing

Tags: html, css, html-table

I want to include HTML table on my project. The problem is that I created a table and it seems to have very little styling, including no borders at all. I commented out my CSS code, JS code and most parts of HTML code and tried it out in multiple situations but still nothing. I also tried it in 3 different browsers (Brave, Chrome, Edge). What am I missing? I don't use Bootstrap or whatever so styling is not compromised by 3rd party library.

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="input-container" id="income-input-container">
    <h4>Add income</h4>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Name" id="income-name">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Amount" id="income-amount">
    <input type="date" value="2022-03-15" min="2010-01-01" max="2022-03-15" id="income-date">
    <select id="income-category">
      <option value="Not categorized">Not categorized</option>
      <option value="Job">Job</option>
      <option value="Business">Business</option>
      <option value="Investments">Investments</option>
    </select>
    <button class="submit-button">Submit</button>
  </div>
  <div class="input-container" id="expense-input-container">
    <h4>Add expense</h4>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Name" id="expense-name">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Amount" id="expense-amount">
    <input type="date" value="2022-03-15" min="2010-01-01" max="2022-03-15" id="expense-date">
    <select id="expense-category">
      <option value="Not categorized">Not categorized</option>
      <option value="Clothing">Clothing</option>
      <option value="Medical">Medical</option>
      <option value="Hobbies">Hobbies</option>
      <option value="Travel">Travel</option>
      <option value="Bills">Bills</option>
    </select>
    <button class="submit-button">Submit</button>
  </div>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Type</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Category</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>This name</td>
        <td>This type</td>
        <td>200$</td>
        <td>2021-03-04</td>
        <td>Travel</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: So the close votes are likely because it either wasn't clear to people what you expected the table to look like OR they were expecting to see something in the code where you attempted to style it (especially since it's tagged with CSS). If you could [edit] your question to indicate that [you expected there to be borders by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71499419/html-table-borders-not-showing#comment126373526_71499565), that would make the question clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initial a table has no styles. You have to style it on your own.

Here is minimalistic working example:

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Type</th>
      <th>Amount</th>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Category</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>This name</td>
      <td>This type</td>
      <td>200$</td>
      <td>2021-03-04</td>
      <td>Travel</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And here are some informations about [styling a table](https://css-tricks.com/complete-guide-table-element/#aa-basic-styling)

Comment: That's cool but im trying to figure out cause of why there is no default styling.

Comment: Ok I thought it does come with default borders, thanks!

Comment: The default styling of an HTML page comes from the browser itself. If the browser does not provide a style for tables then there's no default style. In my opinion, it's good the browser has only minimal default styles so we don't have to manually reset all of them.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your CSS :
`border-style: solid;`. This will create a black line as border around the table.

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playdemo.asp?filename=playcss_border-style&preval=solid

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possibility for simple CSS rules which do a little bit of styling:

`border-collapse: collapse` prevents double borders, the `padding` for the cells is optional (creates some space between cell contents and border), as is the `margin` for the `table` which creates some top/bottom distance. The `border`-settings can be varied as desired (style, thickness, color)

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 1em 0;
}

th,
td {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 3px 6px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:wght@300;400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="wrapper">

    <div class="input-container" id="income-input-container">
      <h4>Add income</h4>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Name" id="income-name">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Amount" id="income-amount">
      <input type="date" value="2022-03-15" min="2010-01-01" max="2022-03-15" id="income-date">
      <select id="income-category">
        <option value="Not categorized">Not categorized</option>
        <option value="Job">Job</option>
        <option value="Business">Business</option>
        <option value="Investments">Investments</option>
      </select>

      <button class="submit-button">Submit</button>
    </div>

    <div class="input-container" id="expense-input-container">
      <h4>Add expense</h4>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Name" id="expense-name">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Amount" id="expense-amount">
      <input type="date" value="2022-03-15" min="2010-01-01" max="2022-03-15" id="expense-date">
      <select id="expense-category">
        <option value="Not categorized">Not categorized</option>
        <option value="Clothing">Clothing</option>
        <option value="Medical">Medical</option>
        <option value="Hobbies">Hobbies</option>
        <option value="Travel">Travel</option>
        <option value="Bills">Bills</option>
      </select>

      <button class="submit-button">Submit</button>
    </div>

    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Type</th>
          <th>Amount</th>
          <th>Date</th>
          <th>Category</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>This name</td>
          <td>This type</td>
          <td>200$</td>
          <td>2021-03-04</td>
          <td>Travel</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

  </div>
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

check: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_table_borders.asp

First of all, in your html, you can give a "border" attribute equals to "1" to your table element like this:

```
<table border=1>
```

Now you will have borders but "double borders". if you check the link from w3schools, you can see some css styles you can write to change how borders look.  For example:

```
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Comment: The `border` attribute is [deprecated for tables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table#border).